# Convert string to LocalDateTime or OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, date, localdatetime

I have the following code:

```
String dateTimeInStr = "17-Jul-2020 12:12";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
       // OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeInStr, formatter);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeInStr, formatter);
        System.out.println(localDateTime);
     //   System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
```

As you can see I try convert string 17-Jul-2020 12:12 to the LocalDateTime or OffsetDateTime. But nothing works.

```
Text '17-Jul-2020 12:12' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,1]]=2020, MonthOfYear=7, DayOfMonth=17},ISO resolved to 12:12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Case-sensitive

You are using uppercase 'YYYY' which is the `week year`. Try with lowercase 'yyyy':

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

## `Locale`

And specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) for the human language and cultural norms used in translating the name of month.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm")
        .withLocale( Locale.US );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/cNqwGx).

> 2020-07-17T12:12

Comment: I'm on phone and can't check but I'm pretty sure that it still won't work. The information about the seconds is missing to create a `LocalDateTime`. You need to provide a default for it.

Comment: @akuzminykh, it works. I checked)

Comment: @DenB Just for me: Could you check, which second it got? Is it just zero?

Comment: seconds and milliseconds are 00 and 000

Comment: @akuzminykh, yes it's 0